# How to get a pointer to a hardware driver in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, malware

I want to write a program that will monitor memory in a driver and print the memory contents every so often.

However, I'm not finding any resources in the Windows API that seem to allow me to grab a pointer (Handle) to a specific driver.

I'd appreciate any answer either from User space OR kernel space.

If you want to know *exactly* what I'm doing, I'm attempting to duplicate the results from [this](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mikepo/papers/gpukeylogger.eurosec13.pdf) paper except on Windows.  After I gain the ability to monitor a buffer in a basic windows console program, I intend to monitor from the GPU.

[For the record:  I am a Graduate Student who is pursuing this as a summer project... this is ethical malware research.]

============UPDATE  ==================

This might technically be better suited as an answer, but not really until I have a working solution.

My initial plan of attack is to use WinDbg to do dynamic analysis on the keyboard driver when it gets loaded, so I can get some idea about normal loading/unloading behavior.  I'm using chapter 10 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007ED2XDS), to guide setting up my testbed and once I understand more about the keyboard structure and its buffer, I'll work backwards towards getting a permanent reference to this structure and see about passing it into the graphics card and monitoring it with DMA as the original paper did on Linux.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to [write your own Windows driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has access to Kernel land and can monitor memory there, then that could send data to your monitor app.

Comment: Also, there's no call for a general "dump memor if that drivr"-interface. So, you must write your own for each driver. Beware of all concurrency issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't solve this problem by "grabbing a pointer to a specific driver". You need to locate the specific buffer used by the keyboard driver that resides on top of the USB driver.

You will have to actually grok the keyboard and USB drivers for Windows. At least part of which is probably available if you have a DDK (driver development kit) [aka WDK, Windows Driver Kit]. You will definitely need a graphics driver for this part of the project.

You will also have to develop a driver mechanism to map an arbitrary (kernel) lump of memory to your graphics driver - which means you need access to the source code for the graphics driver. (In theory, you could perhaps hack about in the page-tables, but Windows itself isn't too keen on software messing with the page-tables, and you'd definitely need to be VERY careful if the system is SMP, since modifying page-tables in an SMP system requires that you flush the TLB's of the "other" CPU(cores) in the system after updates).

To me, this seems like a rather interesting project, but a really tough one in a closed source system like Windows. At least in Linux, the developer has the source-code to read. When it comes to Windows, most of the relevant source code is completely unavailable (unless your school has special license to the MS Source code - I think there are some that do).

Comment: You gave me some useful information here, I'm going to use WinDbg to analyze the driver as its loaded and attempt to discover where its storing keyboard data at runtime... that should at least get me to where I can get a permanent reference to the struct in question.